# Multiple Slider didn't works well?

Tags: xcode, int, slider, double, swiftui

Hi I'm Korean student who make self diagnosis page of application
I made self diagnosis page by slider. I need 8 slider cuz I have 8 Questions.
At first I made first slider, it works well. But, I made more slider I got error message. I wanna delete error message to make my page works well. I tried everything that swift suggest. 
I wonder why error message appear after made second and more slider

Here is my code, I using SwiftUI, my Xcode version is 11.2.1

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var value1: Double = 0
@State private var value2: Double = 0
@State private var value3: Double = 0
@State private var value4: Double = 0
@State private var value5: Double = 0
@State private var value6: Double = 0
@State private var value7: Double = 0
@State private var value8: Double = 0
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("앉아서 책(신문 잡지 서류 등)을 읽을 때")
        Slider(value: $value1,in: 0...3, step: 1).padding(.horizontal,30)
        HStack {
            Text("전혀").offset(x:17)
            Spacer()
            Text("조금").offset(x:22)
            Spacer()
            Text("상당히").offset(x:20)
            Spacer()
            Text("매우 많이")
        }.padding(.horizontal,10)
        Text("TV볼 때")
        Slider(value: $value2,in: 0...3, step: 1).padding(.horizontal,30)
        HStack {
            Text("전혀").offset(x:17)
            Spacer()
            Text("조금").offset(x:22)
            Spacer()
            Text("상당히").offset(x:20)
            Spacer()
            Text("매우 많이")
        }.padding(.horizontal,10)
        Text("공공장소(모임, 극장 등)에서 가만히 앉아 있을 때")
        Text("정차 없이 1시간 동안 운행 중인 차에 승객으로 앉아 있을 때")
        Text("오후에 주위상황이 허락되어 쉬려고 누워 있을 때")
        Text("앉아서 상대방과 이야기 할 때")
        Text("반주를 곁들이지 않은 점심식사 후 조용히 앉아 있을 때")
        Text("교통 혼잡으로 몇 분 동안 멈춰선 차 안에서")
    }
}
}
```

Also If I made value1 to Int, swift make error that

```
Initializer 'init(value:in:step:onEditingChanged:)' requires that 'Int.Stride' (aka 'Int') conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'
```

So I change

```
Slider(value: $value1,in: 0...3, step: 1).padding(.horizontal,30)
to
Slider(value: $value1,in: 0...3, step: 1.0).padding(.horizontal,30)
```

then I got new error message at

```
.padding(.horizontal,10)
and error message is
'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'
```

I just wanna know that what is the matter.

I would appreciate it if you could suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is SwiftUI mis-error. You just have too many views in one container (top VStack in your case). It is **not allowed to have more than 10**, so just use Group like below (or make subview for similar pattern and extract it separately)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value1: Double = 0
    @State private var value2: Double = 0
    @State private var value3: Double = 0
    @State private var value4: Double = 0
    @State private var value5: Double = 0
    @State private var value6: Double = 0
    @State private var value7: Double = 0
    @State private var value8: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("앉아서 책(신문 잡지 서류 등)을 읽을 때")
                Slider(value: $value1,in: 0...3, step: 1).padding(.horizontal,30)
                HStack {
                    Text("전혀").offset(x:17)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("조금").offset(x:22)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("상당히").offset(x:20)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("매우 많이")
                }.padding(.horizontal,10)
            }
            Group {
                Text("TV볼 때")
                Slider(value: $value2,in: 0...3, step: 1).padding(.horizontal,30)
                HStack {
                    Text("전혀").offset(x:17)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("조금").offset(x:22)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("상당히").offset(x:20)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("매우 많이")
                }.padding(.horizontal,10)
            }

            // ... other grouped sliders here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!!! I know that container not allowed to have more than 10 but, I have never thought this error is caused by this problem thank you a lot!!